# CountIFS and ImportRange

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to count the data after importing the data from another excel and on conditions on 2 different columns:

First condition :

```
=COUNTIFS(IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1suV8EPH4HtwAEuBX6XpQ3dLsUrFHasgMHFVFJRR4j6M/edit#gid=168725841","Flow!K6:K3000"),B6,IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1suV8EPH4HtwAEuBX6XpQ3dLsUrFHasgMHFVFJRR4j6M/edit#gid=168725841","Flow!F6:F3000"),"=Complete")
```

I want to count the number of rows with

```
Flow!K6:K3000 = B6 (a string) and Flow!F6:F3000 "=Complete"
```

The output is always coming out as 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it is not necessary to put "=" in your formula. You may try the below.

> =COUNTIFS(IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1suV8EPH4HtwAEuBX6XpQ3dLsUrFHasgMHFVFJRR4j6M/edit#gid=168725841","Flow!K6:K3000"),B6,IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1suV8EPH4HtwAEuBX6XpQ3dLsUrFHasgMHFVFJRR4j6M/edit#gid=168725841","Flow!F6:F3000"),"Complete")